# Drupal 8 customize duplicate view fields

Tags: theming, 8

I have view for taxonomy and it has default name field duplicated, one with link and the other without link.

I have changed the one without link by creating `views-view-field--myviewname--name.html.twig` template file and it is ok.

But I need to change the other one with link, with some classes and I want to keep the link but want to have custom text for the link. The views-view-field--myviewname--name.html.twig file only applies to the first one(the one without link). I want to customize other one(with link) differently. How to do that? Is there any naming convention? The debug comments does not suggest anything.

Comment: Probably `views-view-field--myviewname--name-1.html.twig`

Comment: @NoSssweat Thanks it worked. But that does not give me the control of the field anchor tag.

Comment: Did you try writing your own link? `<a href="/something">Custom Text</a>`